# Magneto1 I have getting error in console product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, error, product-view, console

I have getting error in prototype.js product detail page if any one idea please share your inputs as soon as .

```
TypeError: Form.Element.Serializers[method] is not a function
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)